# How to deserialize element with attribute

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm consuming a RESTful web service by using RESTSharp. One of the XML elements looks like the following:

```
<temp_c units="°C">7.9</temp_c>
```

And the C# class POCO is as follows:

```
public class Test
{
    public TempC temp_c { get; set; }
}

public class TempC
{
    public string units { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

When I use RESTSharp, I get the `TempC` object populated with units but not with an actual value; e.g. 7.9. The value is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the problem by changing the property value to Value.

More detail example is here:
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Answer (score 0):

You need to put [XmlText] annotation in that case

```
public class TempC
    {
        public string units { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

This will tell De-serializer to get that from body of tag.

Reference link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.xml/loj2CBoyCnE