# Deserialize XML with Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, restsharp

I'm having trouble deserializing an XML response from an API call. My 'Option' object's property 'Description' is null.

Below is a sample of the XML:

```
<vehicle found="1">
   <description>VehicleDescText</description>
   <buildDate>2000-11-20</buildDate>
   <modelYear>2001</modelYear>
   <optionList>
      <option code="UH8">OptionDesc1</option>
      <option code="UH8">OptionDesc2</option>
   </optionList>
</vehicle>
```

Here is a sample of C# classes:

```
[DataContract]
[XmlRoot("vehicle")]
public class Vehicle
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlAttribute("found")]
    public bool Found { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("buildDate")]
    public string BuildDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("modelYear")]
    public string ModelYear { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("optionList")]
    public List<Option> OptionList { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("option")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing the object looks like this:

```
var xmlDeserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer();
results = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Vehicle>(response);
```

Where am I going wrong here?  As I would prefer not to modify the underlying data model, what Attributes can I add or modify to fix the problem?

Comment: The XML sample you provided has Vehicle for root, not ResponseResult. Shouldn't you be calling Deserialize<Vehicle> instead?

Comment: @GabrielRainha I cannot create a wrapper class for the Vehicle?

Comment: If your response is not wrapping a Vehicle, no. Is that sample XML an exact copy of your response object?

Comment: You should be deserializing the vehicle.

Comment: It is an abridged response. Identical in structure, though. I moved the XmlRoot attribute to my ResponseResult declaration. Still a null object on serialization. Going to remove the wrapper and see what happens.. I don't NEED it

Comment: I have edited the code to what I am working with now. The only thing coming back as null at the moment is the Description property on Option

Comment: What is `XmlDeserializer`?  Does it use `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`?  Can you provide a [mcve] we can compile, run and test?

Comment: @dbc RestSharp.Deserializers is where XmlSerializer comes from

Comment: `RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer` doesn't use data contract attributes or `XmlSerializer` attributes.  It has its own.  See https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization.  Maybe you want to use [`DotNetXmlDeserializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/DotNetXmlDeserializer.cs) instead?

Comment: Could you try use [XmlText] instead of [XmlElement("option")]? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245846/deserializing-xml-file-with-multiple-element-attributes-attributes-are-not-des

Comment: You need to rename `Description` to `Value` as explained in [How to deserialize element with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227365/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @dbc Datacontract attributes are for something else. I'll give this a shot if I cannot get this going without changing property names.

Comment: @rudolf_franek I will certainly try this tomorrow. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read docs: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Change `Description` property to `Value` property and it will work (in `Option` class).

Can't give you better answer because I have never used RestSharp :)

Comment: If I cannot get this going without changing property names I will give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, the property does have to be named Value.

Comment: @MikeViscontini: user `dbc` added better answer.

Answer (score 7):

You have marked your types with [XML serializer attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization) and [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx), but the deserializer you are using, [`RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/XmlDeserializer.cs), does not support these attributes.

Instead, as explained in its [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization), it supports the [`[DeserializeAs]`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/DeserializeAsAttribute.cs) attribute which allows for control of XML node name and element vs. attribute status.

But as noted in [@apocalypse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024374/3744182) as well as [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12223369/3744182) there is a special case in the documentation regarding deserialization of element values into property values:

> If the XML returned is like this:
>
> ```
> <Response>Hello world</Response>
> ```
>
> There's no way to directly represent that in a C# class:
>
> ```
> public class Response {
> }
> ```
>
> You need something to hold the value of the Response element. In this
>   case, add a property called Value and it will be populated:
>
> ```
> public class Response {
>      public string Value { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> This condition is checked for between searching for matching element
>   names and matching attribute names.

I.e. if your rename `Description` to `Value` you will be able to deserialize that XML successfully.  ([Sample fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MMPn0d).)

However, it appears you do not wish to rename your `Description` property.  If so, you can instead apply `[DeserializeAs(Name = "Value")]` to it and the special case will again apply:

```
public class Option
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "Value")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5mDPpg).

Finally, as an alternative solution you could switch to [`RestSharp.Deserializers.DotNetXmlDeserializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/DotNetXmlDeserializer.cs) and use regular `XmlSerializer` attributes, specifically [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx).  Thus your code would become:

```
var xmlDeserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.DotNetXmlDeserializer();
var results = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Vehicle>(response);
```

And your types would look like:

```
[XmlRoot("vehicle")]
public class Vehicle
{
    [XmlAttribute("found")]
    public bool Found { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("buildDate")]
    public string BuildDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("modelYear")]
    public string ModelYear { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("optionList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("option")]
    public List<Option> OptionList { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle #3](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WtqlkF).

Answer (score 1):

In the XML, the value you want isn't an inner XmlElement - it's the current XmlElement's value.

You could mark the `Option` class' `Description` property with `XmlText` instead of `XmlElement`.

See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524289/38368).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow as well as apocalypse's answer